# How do I configure pgAdmin to use a fixed port?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

pgAdmin4 starts on an unpredictable port. I would like to fix it so it always uses the same port.

[According to the docs I can configure this through a plist file](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.23/desktop_deployment.html#runtime), but that file is overridden on starting pgAdmin4.

How can I specify a fixed port to run pgAdmin4 on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version you are using.

### v5.x

Because of the change to a standalone application this setting is moved to:

- Click on "File v" next to the pgAdmin logo in the top bar.
- Click on "Runtime >" and "Configure..."
- The first section is about "Fixed Port"

### v4.x

- Click on the pgAdmin 4 tray-icon
- Click "Configure..."
- Check the box labeled "Fixed Port Number?"
- Enter the desired port number in the field next to it

Source: https://superuser.com/a/1476745/516502

**Note:** Some version pre v4.26 had a bug where it ignored the value.
This was [fixed in v4.26 (issue #5773)](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/release_notes_4_26.html).