# Fatal error issue while setting up pgadmin4 in windows 10 with PostgeSQL 14.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am beginning with phoenix and PostgreSQL 14.4. I have installed PostgreSQL successfully. But now when I am trying to set up pgadmin4 it shows me some fatal error.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. But I couldn't resolve the error.

> 2022-07-13 12:33:41,767: WARNING  werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not
> available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
>
> - Serving Flask app 'pgadmin' (lazy loading)
> - Environment: production    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in
>   a production deployment.    Use a production WSGI server instead.
> - Debug mode: off

> 2022-07-13 12:33:41,769: ERROR    pgadmin:    Error starting the app server:
> (<class 'OSError'>, OSError(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a
> socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions', None, 10013,
> None), <traceback object at 0x000002227BBCEE80>)

It would be very helpful if you could help.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this question has nothing to do with [tag:elixir] nor [tag:phoenix-framework].

Answer (score 0):

I guess the port pgadmin is trying to run is being used by another application. Or applications may be restricted by Windows to open ports. My advice is to try to run it by changing the port as described below;

- Click on the pgAdmin 4 tray-icon
- Click "Configure..."
- Check the box labeled "Fixed Port Number?"
- Enter the desired port number in the field next to it

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006199/13756006

If that also fails you may need to check port permissions in Windows (firewall etc, whoever is controlling these permissions on windows)

Comment: I think it was just a network issue because it started working just fine on it's own.